# Entire function restricted on an open bounded subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function and $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let
$S=\{Re(f(z)))+Im(f(z)) : z\in \Omega\}$. Then which of the following is/are  necessarily correct ?

$(1)S$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$

$(2)S$ is a closed  set in $\mathbb{R}$

$(3)S$ is a open set in $\mathbb{C}$

$(4)S$ is a discrete set in $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt

Some general observations:-

By Open Mapping Theorem ,$f(\Omega)$ is also open in $\mathbb{C}$. So

$f(\Omega )=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha
\in I }B_{\alpha }$  where $I$ is some index set and $B_{\alpha}=B(z_{\alpha},r_{\alpha})$ by the metric topology

I claim $S_{\alpha}=\{Re(w)+Im(w) : w\in B_{\alpha}\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

A probable Proof :-

Let $w \in B_{\alpha}$. Then $w=z_{\alpha}+r(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta))$ for some $r$ and $\theta$ satsifying $0\le r \lt r_{\alpha}$ and $0\le \theta \lt 2\pi$

Let $z_{\alpha}=x_{\alpha}+iy_{\alpha}$

Then $S_{\alpha}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{r,\theta}\{x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha}+rcos(\theta)+rsin(\theta)\}$ with $r$ and $\theta$ satisfying the above conditions

$\Rightarrow S_{\alpha}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{r} \displaystyle\bigcup_{\theta}\{ 
  x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha}+ r \sqrt(2)sin(\theta +\pi/4)\}$

$\Rightarrow S_{\alpha}= 
 \displaystyle\bigcup_{r} [ x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha} -r \sqrt(2),  x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha}+ r\sqrt(2) ]$

$\Rightarrow S_{\alpha}= (x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha}
 -r_{\alpha} \sqrt(2), 
 x_{\alpha}+y_{\alpha} +r_{\alpha}\sqrt(2))$

Hence the claim follows .

What really makes doubtful is the transition from second last step to last step in above proof. This is the same question as

$\displaystyle\bigcup_{0\le r \lt R}[a-br,a+br]=^{?}(a-bR,a+bR)  $ for some non-zero $a$ and $b$.

Of course, if this proof is correct then it is not difficult to see $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ since then it would be (arbitary) union of open intervals.

Again assuming the proof to be true, I can see (at least intuitively) that $S$ is neither an open nor clossed subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

So basically ,my answer is depending on the truthfulness of the above proof.

Do you have any suggestions ? Any alternative ideas are appreciated.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: what about if you show that the projection maps from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$ ($z \to \Re z, \Im z$) are open maps too and then that the sumset of open sets in $\mathbb R$ is open as these two facts imply immediatetly that $S$ is open in $\mathbb R$; obviously no real set can be open in $\mathbb C$, no open non-empty set is discrete (in $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$), while the only that $S$ would be closed were if it would fill the full real line but that is not possible by boundness of $\Omega$ and $f$ continuos on $\bar \Omega$

Comment: Sorry , I didn't get the map actually. Is it $z\to (Re(z),Im(z))$ .I mean the open interval on right side. Please clear this.

Comment: Sorry - I was talking about each map individually from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb R$, so the projections on the coordinate axes regarded as maps into the (same) reals; this implies that the image of $\Re f$ is open as a real set, same for the image of $\Im f$, so it remains to show that the sum of open sets is open

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume $\Omega$ is a connected open set and $f$ is holomorphic and nonconstant on $\Omega.$

Lemma 1: Let $f=u+iv.$ Then $u+v$ is nonconstant on $\Omega.$

Proof: Suppose otherwise. Then $u+v\equiv c,$ where $c$ is a real constant. The C-R equations then imply

$$u_x=-u_y,\,\, u_y= u_x.$$

This implies $u_x=0=u_y$ in $\Omega.$ Since $\Omega$ is connected, $u$ is constant in $\Omega.$ Hence so is $v.$ That implies $f$ is constant in $\Omega,$ contradiction, and the lemma is proved.

Lemma 2: If $w$ is a nonconstant real harmonic function on $\Omega,$ then $w(\Omega)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb R.$

Proof: Because $\Omega$ is connected, $w(\Omega)$ is connected, hence is an interval. Now go through the cases: Could $w(\Omega)=[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb R?$ If so, then $w$ has a maximum in $\Omega,$ which by the maximum principle implies $w$ is constant, contradiction. All cases other than $(a,b)$ can be similarly excluded (here $-\infty \le a<b\le \infty$).

Conclusion: $S$ open in $\mathbb R$ must hold. The other options need not hold.

Note: It seems irrelevant that $f$ is entire or $\Omega$ is bounded. But assuming $\Omega$ is connected is crucial.

Comment: Thanks sir. I can see your's and @Conrad approach are same. Please expand your answer for discarding  $w(\Omega)=(a,b]$  only . Also even if $\Omega$ is not connected can't the result be applied to each individual connected component?

Comment: If $w(\Omega) = (a,b],$ then $w$ has a max in $\Omega,$ ... If $\Omega$ is not connected, then none of (1) ... (4) need hold.